# How to find the Google account associated with my Google Analytics tracking code

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have fogotten the account used to create the Google Analytics code for my website. Is it possible to figure out which email is associated with the Google account that has been used to create the code?

Answer (score -1):

You would need to call Google to get that information.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-issues-related-to-your-accounts-reports-and-data/wYOjIzl6dgI

Comment: Your link is broken.  It takes me to the AdSense forum home page.   Partly because links can break, link only answers are not appropriate here.   It would be good to include the relevant details here.   What is the phone number to call?  Who should they talk to?   What do they need to say?